# Compound Quantifier

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

Can any one help me what will be the universe discourse of these two statements?
if both statement has natural numbers or same universe of discourse what will be values, that makes 1st statement true and 2nd to false, of x and y?

- $\forall x~\exists y~[x < y]$
- $\exists y~\forall x~[x < y]$

Comment: (for all x there is a y such that x < y)

(there is a y for all x such that x < y)

Comment: I am confusing about universe of discourse.

Comment: if i set value of x={1,2,3,4,5} and y ={1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: x=5 and y=5 then first condition will be false.

Comment: whereas a video i watched on youtube that says 1st statement is true and 2nd is false

Comment: could you guide me where i'm wrong?

Comment: The universe of discourse appears to be all natural numbers, not any finite subset.  There is no largest natural number.  (All integers, all rationals, or all reals would also work.)

Comment: could you explain me with an example...what will be values of x and y, that makes 1st statement true and 2nd false?

Answer (score 1):

The writer needs to specify the "universe of discourse" for the formal propositions to be meaningful.  Without specification we can only say that the second proposition implies the first.

If your question is, give a universe of discourse that makes the first statement true and the second statement false, there are many possibilities.

As Graham Kemp points out, taking the natural numbers as the "model" (universe of discourse), then the first statement is true (for every number $x$, a larger number $y$ exists) but the second statement is false (no number is larger than all numbers, clearly).

Another such model/universe of discourse is the real numbers with usual ordering.

Note that it is the choice of a "universe of discourse" that makes one or both of these statements true or false, not (as the OP expresses it) "what will be values, that makes 1st statement true and 2nd to false, of x and y?"

The choice of values "of x and y" would make sense if the variables $x,y$ appeared free (unbound by quantifiers) in the formulas.  But they do not.  Both variables are quantified, $x$ by universal quantification and $y$ by existential quantification.  That means that the truth or falsity of these statements depends on the model (that is, the set of values and the predicate $\lt$ defined for that domain), and not upon any choosing of values for $x,y$.

In particular the formula $x\lt y$ can be true or false among natural numbers depending on how we choose values, but the quantified formulas used in the Question are not affected by such choices.

Comment: Thanks hardmath...I learned from this line..."The choice of values "of x and y" would make sense if the variables x,yx,y appeared free (unbound by quantifiers) in the formulas."...I have a question if x,y have same universe of discourse then how can i imagine x < y or how can i make picture in my mind?...now i'm confused here.

Comment: I assume your "universe of discourse" is what we call a *model* in formal logic.  The subject of first-order logic (or predicate logic) can be developed from two important perspectives.  One is purely syntactic, the manipulation of symbols like variables, quantifiers, and logical connectives, to deduce statements from axioms and assumptions.  The other is *semantic*, dealing with the meaning (interpretation) of sentences.  For this last topic one considers an interpretation of the extra-logical symbols (like $\lt$ in your examples) as predicates defined in a domain such as natural numbers.

Comment: Let me point out, for further reading, [Tarski's Semantic theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_theory_of_truth) and in particular the topic of interpreting sentences that contain quantifiers.  To many the theory will seem "obvious", but it took a smart person to write down the obvious.  The truth of $\forall x\; P(x)$ in an interpretation amounts to the truth of $P(x)$ for every possible choice of $x$ in that interpretation.  The truth of $\exists x\; P(x)$ likewise corresponds to the truth of $P(x)$ for at least one choice of $x$.

Comment: thanks for your response hardmath....I had network problem...now im back...leave those statement....the below new statements have right model I think ....hardmath could you explain me how 1st statement is true and 2nd one is false?

Suppose P(x; y) is "xy = 1", the universe of discourse for x
is the set of positive integers, and the universe of discourse for y is the set of real
numbers.

Comment: (1) ∀x∃yP(x; y) may be read For every positive integer x there is a real number
y such that xy = 1. This proposition is true.
(2) ∃y∀xP(x; y) may be read There exists a real number y such that, for every
positive integer x, xy = 1. This proposition is false.

Comment: no I don't have grasp of the setup...I'm confused about reading of these kind of statements...my confusion is I take same meaning of these two statement, all x are less than a y...
∀x ∃y [x<y], 
∃y ∀x [x<y]
I did not understand first two statements then I posted new statements for understanding may be there is someone who can explain easily.

Comment: You are welcome to post a new Question, but you haven't been very clear about what you did not understand about my Answer to your first Question.  I thought you understood that while every number $x$ has a number $y$ larger than $x$, there is no number $y$ that is larger than every number $x$.  The order of these quantifiers makes a difference.